# Bounded priority queue in ZIO

Tags: scala, concurrency, functional-programming, zio

There is [`TPriorityQueue`](https://zio.dev/docs/datatypes/stm/tpriorityqueue) in ZIO which is unbounded. Is there a way to adapt it to become bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about performance too much you can do something quick and dirty like this:

```
case class TPW(tpq: TPriorityQueue[Int]) {
  def offer(e: Int) = ZSTM.whenM(tpq.size.map(_ < 50))(tpq.offer(e))
  // .. other methods
}
```

This would be a dropping queue.